# How can I get a vim plugin's directory from within that plugin?

Tags: vim

I need to copy a file from my plugin's directory but I don't know how to get a string containing the plugin's directory? I know where I have the plugin installed on my machine but I want the plugin to work on other people's machines including Windows. How do i do this?

Comment: Why do you need to copy something from your plugin's directory? Why don't you just put it in the correct spot when the plugin is installed?

Comment: I have to copy it and modify it for the user's project. It's not a static file.

Comment: I would put the content of that file in a variable and write it to a file in the user's project when needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To get the plugin directory's full path you can use the following to get the directory when the plugin is sourced and store it in a variable.

```
let s:plugindir = expand('<sfile>:p:h:h')
```

The latter you would just use the variable to get the plugin directory.

`expand()` expands the the wildcards into a string.
`<sfile>` is the file being sourced.
`:p` makes the name a full path when it is expanded.
`:h` removes the file name.
`:h` remove the filename again (in this case should be the plugin directory)

Take a look at `:h filename-modifiers` and `:h expand()`

Comment: That does not appear to do what I want. I want something like, "/home/steven/.vim/bundle/myplugin"

Comment: @SteveDeFacto add another `:h` to remove the plugin directory from the path

Comment: That returns the current working directory. I highly doubt <sfile> is what I need.

Comment: @SteveDeFacto hmm this works for me... Or at least I think it does. When I put `echo expand('<sfile>:p:h:h')` in `~/.vim/plugin/dir.vim`. I get `/home/fdinoff/.vim` as output

Comment: @SteveDeFacto Store the output of expand in a variable in your plugin and then let your functions use that variable latter.

Comment: This didn't work for me until I did what @FDinoff did. Calling it as a var in a function `let dir = expand(...)` did not work. But at the top of the script calling `let s:dir = expand(..)` did.